# setup problems nginx darksky cors proxy

Tags: nginx, cors, fetch-api, darksky

I am currently trying to implement a own cors proxy based on nginx. For testing I try to request the data from the darksky api.
The problem is that I always get the response that I don't have the access-control-allow-origin header set.
What do I do wrong here?

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name proxy.mydomain.rocks;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.error.log;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
    add_header "Content-Type" 'application/json';
    add_header "Accept" "application/json";
    add_header "Vary" "Origin" always;

    # darksky api
    location ~ ^/weather/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass https://api.darksky.net/forecast/my-api-key/$1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
            proxy_set_header "Content-Type" "application/json";
            proxy_set_header "Accept" "application/json";
            proxy_set_header "Origin" "http://proxy.mydomain.rocks";
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
            proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    }
}
```

and here is my js fetchApi Request:

```
let targetUrl = 'http://proxy.mydomain.rocks/weather/' + lat + ',' + lng + '?units=si&country=de';
let response = await fetch(targetUrl);
console.log(response);
let data = await response.json();
return data;
```

Hope you can help me with that.
Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a  solution for myself:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name proxy.mydomain.rocks;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.error.log;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;

    # darksky api
    location ~ ^/weather/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass https://api.darksky.net/forecast/my-api-key/$1$is_args$args;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST,GET,OPTIONS' always;
    }
```

}